# How to create a table every X element in a table?

Tags: javascript

sorry I don't speak English very well.

I have a table with several elements, I want to return all the X elements a new table inside a table.

For example:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
```

```
let newArr = [
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9],
[10,11,12],
];
```

This is the way I am currently doing this :

```
const size = shuffleImages.length / 4

while (shuffleImages.length > 0) {
 columns.push(shuffleImages.splice(0, size))
}
```

I would like to understand how to do this without using  `while` and instead use for example `.map` or is there just an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the array into small array using `map` and than `slice` it :

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

var chunkSize = 3;

const groups =  arr.map( function(e,i){ 
     return i%chunkSize===0 ? arr.slice(i,i+chunkSize) : null; 
}).filter((e) =>e);

console.log(groups);
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, is just perfect and I can fully understand your manipulation

Comment: You are more than welcome :)